# Как получить корректный номер месяца в moment js?

Tags: node.js, momentjs

```js
const now = new Date();
const formatedDateAppend = moment(now).format('D-M-YYYY');
console.log(formatedDateAppend);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Сейчас октябрь. Но вместо 4.9.2018, он выводит 4.10.2018.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы номер месяца начинался не с 0, а с 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://momentjs.com/docs/

> M MM  1..12   Month number

просто октябрь 10-й месяц.